# Roslyn Syntax Rewriter How to add Using Directives from within VisitMethodDeclaration

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using Roslyn to rewrite several methods in various projects and inject a method parameter in certain cases.  This works, creating output similar to the following:

```
GetFilter(Data.Application.Interfaces.IDataSession session, string name)
```

What I want it to do however is to add a Using Directive to the class and add the parameter just as:

```
GetFilter(IDataSession session, string name)
```

I've looked at several examples but I'm missing something.  When I add the following code to update the Using's it stops doing anything at all.

```
public class DbBaseReferencesMethodRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        if (RewriterUtility.HasDriveSessionParameter(node)) return node;

        // Start: Add to Using Directives
        var qualifiedName = SyntaxFactory.ParseName("Data.Application.Interfaces");
        var usingDirective = SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(qualifiedName);
        var rootNode = node.SyntaxTree.GetRoot() as CompilationUnitSyntax;
        rootNode = rootNode.AddUsings(usingDirective).NormalizeWhitespace();
        // End:  Add to Using Directives

        return CreatesDbBaseWithParameterlessConstructor(node)
            ? node.PrependParameter(RewriterUtility.CreateDriveSessionParameter())
            : node;
    }

    private static bool CreatesDbBaseWithParameterlessConstructor(SyntaxNode node)
    {  
        return node.DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax>()
            .Any(RewriterUtility.HasParameterlessDbBaseCall);
    }
}
```

Comment: You create a new `rootNode` but doesn't apply it to the existing syntax tree)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private (SyntaxTree, SyntaxTree) UpdateUsingDirectivesForChanges((SyntaxTree, SyntaxTree) change)
{
    var qualifiedName = SyntaxFactory.ParseName(" Data.Application.Interfaces");
    var usingDirective = SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(qualifiedName);
    var rootNode = change.Item2.GetRoot() as CompilationUnitSyntax;
        
    if (!rootNode.Usings.Select(d => d.Name.ToString()).Any(u => u == qualifiedName.ToString()))
    {
        rootNode = rootNode.AddUsings(usingDirective);
        change.Item2 = rootNode.SyntaxTree;
    }

    return change;
}
```